# R subsetting, grouping, and piping

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, subset

| YEAR | MONTH | AVG.TEMP | REGION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1962 | 1 | 67 | South |
| 1962 | 2 | 68 | South |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1982 | 12 | 66 | South |
| 1962 | 1 | 54 | Midwest |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1982 | 12 | 71 | West |

I have data similar to what is shown above describing the average temperature of three US regions for each month from 1962 to 1982. My goal is to create another data set that contains the combined average temperature for each month, for each region. So, it would be something like:

| Month | Region | Avg temp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | South | 67 |
| 2 | South | 68 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 11 | Midwest | 46 |
| 12 | Midwest | 44 |

I have tried different cominations of piping similar to:

```
test <- temps1962.82 %>% 
          group_by(MONTH) %>% 
          mean(AVG.TEMP)
```

Comment: You may have to try something like `group_by(MONTH, REGION) |> summarise(mean(AVG.TEMP), .groups = "drop") It would be easier to help if you included a sample dataset from the output of `dput(your_data)` .

Comment: To get some R fundamentals (such as grouping and summarizing data) down first, have a look at https://r4ds.had.co.nz/

Answer (score 0):

You were close, just include *REGION* in your grouping and pipe to `summarize`

```
library(dplyr) # >= 1.1.0, below use 'group_by'

temps1962.82 %>% 
  summarize(Avg.temp = mean(AVG.TEMP), .by = c(MONTH, REGION))
  MONTH  REGION Avg.temp
1     1   South       67
2     2   South       68
3    12   South       66
4     1 Midwest       54
5    12    West       71
```

With **base R**

```
aggregate(AVG.TEMP ~ MONTH + REGION, temps1962.82, mean)
  MONTH  REGION AVG.TEMP
1     1 Midwest       54
2     1   South       67
3     2   South       68
4    12   South       66
5    12    West       71
```

##### Data

```
temps1962.82 <- structure(list(YEAR = c(1962L, 1962L, 1982L, 1962L, 1982L), MONTH = 
c(1L, 2L, 12L, 1L, 12L), AVG.TEMP = c(67L, 68L, 66L, 54L, 71L), REGION = c("South", 
"South", "South", "Midwest", "West")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```